# Adding borders to concave SVG composites in Matter,js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm looking to add borders to concave shapes rendered through matter.js. You can see a working example of the matter.js setup here:

```js
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    Common = Matter.Common,
    MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint,
    Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
    Composite = Matter.Composite,
    Vertices = Matter.Vertices,
    Svg = Matter.Svg,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    Common.setDecomp;

// create engine
var engine = Engine.create(),
world = engine.world;

   // create renderer
   var render = Render.create({

       canvas: document.querySelector('#myCanvas'),
       engine: engine,
       options: {
          background: '#eaeaea',
           wireframes: false,
           width: 800,
           height: 800
       }
   });

   Render.run(render);

   // create runner
   var runner = Runner.create();

   // add mouse control
   var mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
       mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
           mouse: mouse,
           constraint: {
               stiffness: 0.2,
               render: {
                   visible: false
               }
           }
       });

    mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener("mousewheel", mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel);
    mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel);

   Composite.add(world, mouseConstraint);

   // keep the mouse in sync with rendering
   render.mouse = mouse;

   // create runner
   var runner = Runner.create();

   // add bodies
   Composite.add(world, [
       // walls: bottom, right, left
       Bodies.rectangle(400, 795, 800, 10, {isStatic: true, render: {opacity: 1}}),

   ]);

   // add bodies
   if (typeof fetch !== 'undefined') {
       var select = function(root, selector) {
           return Array.prototype.slice.call(root.querySelectorAll(selector));
       };

       var loadSvg = function(url) {
           return fetch(url)
               .then(function(response) { return response.text(); })
               .then(function(raw) { return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(raw, 'image/svg+xml'); });
       };



       ([
         'https://assets.codepen.io/6334052/filled-m.svg',
         'https://assets.codepen.io/6334052/border-m.svg',
         'https://assets.codepen.io/6334052/complete-m.svg'
        

       ]).forEach(function(path, i) {
           loadSvg(path).then(function(root) {

               var vertexSets = select(root, 'path').map(function(path) { return Vertices.scale(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 60), 0.5, 0.5); });

               Composite.add(world, Bodies.fromVertices((i * 150)+100, 50, vertexSets, {
                   render: {
                       fillStyle: '#EE9E8A',
                       strokeStyle: '#EE9E8A',
                       lineWidth: 1
                   }
               }, true));
           });
       });

   } else {
       Common.warn('Fetch is not available. Could not load SVG.');
   }



Matter.Runner.run(engine)
Render.run(render);
```

```css
#myCanvas{
  background: #e1e1e1;
  width: 800px;
 height: 800px;
}
```

```html
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/poly-decomp@0.2.1/build/decomp.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathseg@1.2.0/pathseg.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.17.1/matter.min.js'></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<br>
<img width = "250px" src="https://assets.codepen.io/6334052/Screenshot+2021-06-01+at+11.22.58.png" />
```

But I'd like to add a black border to the letter, 've tried various SVG files but it seems that I can only render one colour, and adding borders as per the documentation adds borders to the individual pieces of the composite.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Can I add another elemement to the composite to mimic the border?

Thanks!

CodePen: https://codepen.io/spinder/pen/VwpbMjW

Comment: I'd probably use your own renderer rather than the built-in renderer, which is for prototyping purposes only.